# Replace lambda with method reference in flatMap during array mapping

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, method-reference

Say we have a `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer {
    private Car[] cars;
    // getter, setter, constructor
}
```

and collection of customers which we need to map on cars.

Currently I'm doing it somehow like this:

```
Collection<Customer> customers = ...
customers.stream().flatMap(
        customer -> Arrays.stream(customer.getCars())
)...
```

It works well, but **the code doesn't look elegant**. I'd really like to replace it with code that uses method references which usually looks more readable and more compact. But using a field of array type makes it hard.

**Question:** is there any way of enhancing the `flatMap` call so it will be more readable/compact/clear?

Comment: Well you can do `customers.stream().map(Customer::getCars).flatMap(Arrays::stream)` but IMO your solution is readable and elegant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can split the `flatMap` call into two calls - `map` and `flatMap` - each receiving a method reference:

```
Collection<Customer> customers = ...
customers.stream()
         .map(Customer::getCars)
         .flatMap(Arrays::stream)...
```

Answer (score 7):

Just add a method to `Customer` returning a stream of `Car`s. Using typical naming conventions, it would look like

```
public Stream<Car> cars() {
    return Arrays.stream(cars);
}
```

Then, you can use it like

```
customers.stream().flatMap(Customer::cars)
```

Generally, properties of a mutable type like an array should be handled with care. The only way to prevent modification through a getter, is to make a copy. So providing an alternative method returning a read-only type like a `Stream`, which does not need copying, has additional uses besides making `flatMap` neat.

Comment: This approach has the extra advantage that, if the array of cars is `null`, you can also handle this case in the method: `return cars == null ?
 Stream.empty() : Arrays.stream(cars);`

Answer (score 3):

You could use :

```
 .map(Customer::getCars)
 .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
```

But I don't think this is more `elegant` in any way. And also having everything as methods references like this makes it less readable, for me at least. I should explain myself as why I see this less readable, because there are two stages that I need to understand now when reading this code. why `map` is done and why `flatMap` is done - might seem minor though.